# Postgresql 11 : could not connect to server after reboot on ubuntu desktop

Tags: postgresql

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I fresh installed the postgresql `/var/run/postgresql/` directory contains 2 or 3 files the `.s.PGSQL.5432` was one of them but unfortunately after reboot the system the directory is empty. and getting above error.

I have tried to follow a lot of tutorials available on the internet but unable to fix. Can somebody help me to solve this out please?

**Output After running `$ journalctl -u postgresql`**

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-02-02 10:28:02 IST, end at Fri 2019-02-22 15:57:46 IST
Feb 19 15:36:57 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 15:36:57 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:28:42 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:28:42 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 16:28:46 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 16:28:46 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:34:30 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:35:07 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 16:35:07 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:37:33 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 19 17:42:17 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:42:18 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:57:47 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:59:53 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:59:53 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 18:05:27 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
lines 1-23...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-02-02 10:28:02 IST, end at Fri 2019-02-22 15:57:46 IST. --
Feb 19 15:36:57 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 15:36:57 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:28:42 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:28:42 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 16:28:46 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 16:28:46 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:34:30 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 16:35:07 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 16:35:07 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:37:33 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 19 17:42:17 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:42:18 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:49:20 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:57:47 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 17:59:53 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 19 17:59:53 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 19 18:05:27 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 09:15:24 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 09:15:24 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 09:21:01 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 09:21:01 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 09:37:23 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 09:37:23 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 09:37:23 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 09:37:23 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:13:32 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 10:15:53 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:15:53 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:42:02 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:42:02 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:42:02 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:42:02 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:44:45 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:44:45 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:44:45 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:44:45 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:51:22 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 10:51:22 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:51:23 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 10:51:23 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:13:06 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:13:06 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:13:06 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:13:06 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:16:07 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:16:07 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:16:07 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:16:07 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:17:55 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:17:55 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:17:55 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:17:55 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:20:35 ewb systemd[1]: Reloading PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:20:35 ewb systemd[1]: Reloaded PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:21:08 ewb systemd[1]: Reloading PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:21:08 ewb systemd[1]: Reloaded PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:50:04 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:50:04 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:50:04 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:50:04 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 11:51:28 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 11:52:24 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 11:52:24 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 13:17:00 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 13:46:45 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 13:46:45 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 13:59:00 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 14:01:25 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 14:01:26 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 14:06:01 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 14:08:54 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 14:08:54 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 14:20:41 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 14:20:41 ewb systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 14:20:44 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 14:20:44 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 14:24:31 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 14:25:30 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 14:25:31 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 17:38:16 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 20 17:39:17 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 17:39:17 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Feb 20 18:01:47 ewb systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Reboot --
Feb 22 09:03:59 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 22 09:04:00 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl status postgresql`? (Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1119751/edit) your question and add the output to it.)

Comment: `● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-02-20 14:25:31 IST; 2h 10min ago
 Main PID: 856 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Feb 20 14:25:30 ewb systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Feb 20 14:25:31 ewb systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
`

Comment: It says `active (exited)` instead of `active (running)`. So something happened at startup that caused `postgresql` to fail. Take a look at the postgresql logs in `/var/log` (probably).

Comment: What Should I look there?

Comment: Are there any error messages in `/var/log/postgresql`?

Comment: The log file is empty.

Comment: What is the output of `journalctl -u postgresql`? Again, add the output to your question. It will not fit into a comment.

Comment: Please check the output.